# cannot create a gcloud pub/sub subscription

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I cannot create a gcloud pub/sub subscription. The interface will not allow me to and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.[image] I have validated my domain

Comment: Is there any error or you just can click to the "create" button?

Comment: just can't click the button. no error shown

Comment: So, I guess you are sure that you wrote a the_name_you_decided like this projects/PROJECT_NAME/subscriptoins/THE_NAME_YOU_DECIDED and just wrote the url, right?

Comment: I dont understand your question. I think maybe you have a typo

Comment: Do you mean did i put the url to my website, like http://mywebsite/api as the push end point? if so, yes

Comment: No. Sorry if I was unclear. I mean that there are two gaps to fill. The name of the "subscription name" and then the URL to the "endpoint url". I can't see if you filled it cause both gaps are obfuscated.

Comment: Yes, they are both filled in. the url is not https though..but even adding https in the form field did not enable button

Answer (score 2):

I can make out from your screenshot that you have not entered a name for the subscription. You must write something after the `projects/my-project-xxxxx/subscriptions/`, so that it reads `projects/my-project-xxxxx/subscriptions/subscription-name` - then the create box will be highlighted.